# IP addresses of ubuntu servers which apt-get connects

Tags: networking, apt, server, firewall

My server uses Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have a very restricted firewall (UFW), that is, I have run these commands:

```
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw default deny incoming
```

But, I would like my system to be updated so, I need to enable only the necessary connections, that is, I need to allow the `apt-get` to connect to Ubuntu servers. Which are these servers and which are their IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot tell you, as your sources might be different, depending on your mirror.

To find all IP addresses that you have configured in your sources, you can use a combination of `grep` and `dig +short`.

```bash
grep -Poh 'https?://\K[^:/ ]*' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list \
| xargs dig +short | sort -u
```

- This needs a DNS Server to be available, so you need to allow connection to it in your firewall.
- Note, that IP-addresses might change, so you may need to rerun that.

Comment: I found the IP addresses and I allowed the connection. I also I allowed the connection to DNS but, sudo apt-get update still does not work..